# Xalan-Java and XPath 2.0

Tags: java, xml

If I understood it correctly,
the most up-to-date version of Xalan-Java still implements XPath Version 1.0.
http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/

why is so? why it has not been updated to xpath2.0?
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/

is there a similar library that implements xpath 2.0?

Comment: If you want to know why something hasn't been done, you will have to ask all the people who didn't do it. That's a lot of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) for xpath2.0. Xalan has prototype for it but this is not an 
official build, see http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200212/post70030.html

Comment: I recently moved from Xalan to Saxon for XPath 2.0 support. Very easy transition. +1

Comment: Has anything changed?